# Reduce Google's Word2Vec model with Gensim

Tags: nlp, gensim, word2vec

Loading the complete pre-trained word2vec model by [Google](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7XkCwpI5KDYNlNUTTlSS21pQmM/edit) is time intensive and tedious, therefore I was wondering if there is a chance to remove words below a certain frequency to bring the `vocab` count down to e.g. 200k words.

I found Word2Vec methods in the `gensim` package to determine the word frequency and to re-save the model again, but I am not sure how to `pop`/`remove` vocab from the pre-trained model before saving it again. I couldn't find any hint in the `KeyedVector class` and the `Word2Vec class` for such an operation?

https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/gensim/models/word2vec.py
https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/gensim/models/keyedvectors.py

**How can I select a subset of the vocabulary of the pre-trained word2vec model?**

Comment: I am probably late, but take a look at [this repo](https://github.com/eyaler/word2vec-slim). I think it is precisely what you are looking for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The GoogleNews word-vectors file format doesn't include frequency info. But, it does seem to be sorted in roughly more-frequent to less-frequent order.

And, `load_word2vec_format()` offers an optional `limit` parameter that only reads that many vectors from the given file.

So, the following should do roughly what you've requested:

```
goognews_wordecs = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(`GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz`, binary=True, limit=200000)
```

Comment: In glove, the vocabulary is sorted by frequency https://github.com/stanfordnlp/GloVe/blob/master/src/vocab_count.c#L206. You can convert glove to word2vec and then use the suggestion above.

Answer (score 4):

Do you know about this open list/set of pretrained models - maybe an alternative one would be beneficial to the jumbo Google one? :)

https://github.com/3Top/word2vec-api#where-to-get-a-pretrained-models

I don't know how to do your precise need, but on the Google group there is some discussion on trimming models that might be of use: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gensim/wkVhcuyj0Sg

They reference a recent change also on minimising the model but I knwo that is not exactly what you want.

https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/pull/987